# DLNM and crossreduce(): getting the coefficients behind the cross-basis

Tags: regression-coefficients, splines, lags

I am using the R package `dlnm` to fit a distributed lag non-linear model estimated with `lm()`. One can specify both the exposure and the lag functions.

In the distributed lag non-linear model, how can we move from the regression estimates of the cross-basis to the parameters before the cross-basis transformation?

The following example might help clarify. We run a `dlnm` where the exposure function is specified as a quadratic and the lag structure is linear:

```
library(dlnm)
cb <- crossbasis(chicagoNMMAPS$temp,lag=30,
             argvar=list("poly",degree=2),
             arglag=list("lin"))
model <- lm(cvd~cb,chicagoNMMAPS)
pred <- crosspred(cb,model,at=-20:30)

plot(pred,"slices",lag=0)
```

[image]

I would like to get the coefficients corresponding to this curve.

My dirty way is the following:

```
LAG<-0
SCALE<-attributes(cb)$argvar$scale
ce<-attributes(cb)$argvar$cen

B1<-(summary(model)$coeff[2,1]+summary(model)$coeff[4,1]*LAG)/SCALE
B2<-(summary(model)$coeff[3,1]+summary(model)$coeff[5,1]*LAG)/(SCALE^2)
B0<--(ce*B1+(ce^2)*B2)
```

where B's are the parameters as shown on the graph below:

```
xx<-(-20:30)
xx2<-xx^2
length(xx)
length(xx2)
yhat<-B0+B1*xx+B2*xx2
lines(-20:30,yhat,lty=2,col="blue")
```

[image]

Is there a better way of finding the B's, either a general formula or a command? Would the `crossreduce()` function work? I would like to get the B's when the lag structure is specified as a spline. For instance:

```
cb <- crossbasis(chicagoNMMAPS$temp,lag=30,
             argvar=list("poly",degree=2),
             arglag=list("ns",knots=(1,8))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set the scale parameter in the `argvar` function to 1. The `crossreduce` function then gives the parameters in the original scale. Below a an example:

```
# with a poly of degree 2 with natural splines at knots 3 and 10
library(dlnm)
cb <- crossbasis(chicagoNMMAPS$temp,lag=30,
                 argvar=list("poly",degree=2,scale=1),
                 arglag=list("ns",knots=c(3,10)))
    model <- lm(cvd~cb,chicagoNMMAPS)
    pred <- crosspred(cb,model,at=-20:30)
    plot(pred,"slices",lag=3)
    ce<-attributes(cb)$argvar$cen

xx<-(-20:30)
xx2<-xx^2
redvar<-crossreduce(cb, model,type="lag",value=3)
b1<-redvar$coefficients[1]
    b2<-redvar$coefficients[2]
b0<--(ce*b1+(ce^2)*b2)

yhat<-b0+b1*xx+b2*xx2
lines(-20:30,yhat2,lty=2,col="green")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the coefficients in pred$matfit.

In your case, the first column (pred$matfit[,1]) gives the plotted coefficients at lag 0.